# STM32 Switch Case influcencing operation

Tags: c++, stm32

I've built a state switcher in my C++ software on a STM32 Microcontroller. Basically it works like this

```
appRun(){
    switch(theState){
     case STATE_1:
      function1(&theState);
     break;
     case STATE_2:
      function2(&theState);
     break;
    }
}
```

Each function can change the state if a certain condition is reached.
This works perfectly, until the 27th case is hit. When the 27th case is hit, the microcontroller is reacting strange. When entering the STOP2 Mode (where cpu is stopped, but Ram is preserved) the Controller does not wake up from the STOP2 Mode. When the STOP2 Mode is commented out, and replaced by

```
while(buttonNotPressed());
```

the Problem does not Occur. The important discovery was, that it does not matter, what code is inside the 27th Switch case. If left empty, lot of code, or just one single line it always acts the same.

It is neither a problem of Flash Storage size, or RAM usage, since only 50% of Flash and 10% of RAM are used. The debbuger device shows no hard faults nor other error messages while run.

Comment: So, what happens inside the magic "27th Switch case"? That you have "10% of RAM used" doesn't mean a function `f() { int a[100000000]; }` can't use all the memory, it just has to be bigger. Please post an [MCVE]. As for `the Controller does not wake up from the STOP2 Mode` - how do you wake up from STOP2? Did you think that maybe in the magic "27th Switch case" the interrupt source or peripheral or anything else that wakes you up from STOP2 mode gets disabled?

Comment: I tried various cases of the switch case. Even if i put nothing inside or just some useless assignment like uint8_t x = 1; the error occours. The wakeup from STOP2 is done by a hardware pin or if enabled by software. I only have enabled hardware pin, if a pin is toggled, the cpu wakes up. The true content of the 27th and following switch cases are not done yet.. so my guess is that the problem does not comes from the code inside, but rather from the switch itself.

Comment: So maybe the "26th Switch case" disables STOP2 wakeup source? Maybe something occurs between 26th and 27th case.

Comment: I also tested this, it does not, even when shuffling the cases it does not change. The issue seems to come from adding one more switch case.

Comment: I've now divided the switch function into two, first its going to check "if (case <20)" and then it will either run one switch for 0-20 or another 20-40. And this works fine, another proof that the problem cannot come from inside the functions